# How to inject css / js files from a Blazor Razor Class Library to ASP.NET Core Blazor Project

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

Usual process to import css / js files from a library to a main project is reference them with

`<script src="_content/RazorLib1/hello.js"></script>`

But there are some Blazor libraries like *DevExpress.Blazor* and [this one](https://github.com/jsakamoto/Toolbelt.Blazor.LoadingBar)
that are able to inject their css / js files without explicit them on main project. What is required to do is call the functions **services.AddMyLibrary()** and/or **services.UseMyLibrary()**

How is it possible? I've looked inside Toolbelt.Blazor.LoadingBar library but I didn't find how he reached this behaviour.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

did a blog post for that (German)
https://blog.ppedv.de/post/Razor-Classlibrary-JavaScript-einbinden

Comment: Thank you. your blog post was useful! If I use your code inside each component of my library I will have a <script> tag for each component loaded with the page. I wrote another JS code to inject inside my component. This code will add a <script> tag if and only if it isn't already inside the page. Can I suggest to edit your code inside **jsRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync** as I've done as a reply to my question?

Answer (score 1):

I solved it thanks to [HannesPreishuber](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3512261/hannespreishuber)'s blog post. I suggest following his post changing the js code called inside **jsRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync** with

```
(function() {
   let scripts = document.getElementsByTagName("script");
   let exists = false;
   let index = 0;

   while(index < scripts.length && !exists){
       exists = scripts[index].src.endsWith('_content/RazorClassLibrary1/exampleJsInterop.js');
       index++;
   }

   if(!exists) {
       document.body.appendChild(
           Object.assign (
               document.createElement ('script'), {
                   src: '_content/RazorClassLibrary1/exampleJsInterop.js',
                   type: 'text/javascript'
               }));
       }
})()
```

so the js library will be append once.

Comment: IMO when you found a useful post, instead of just commenting under it, you can at least upvote it if it is not the exact answer you were looking for.